# In Powerapps how to filter the gallery including an All option?

Tags: office365, powerapps

My app has 3 buttons marked Male, Female, and All, which pass search criteria to a variable used in a gallery filter.

All should return both male & female.

I have retained the search text box that the wizard adds, so users might search retail Promotions Starts With "Summer" && Category = "Male".   But users also want to search for all Promotions starting with "Summer" regardless of Male/Female category.  I have a Date Picker in play too.

This formula is applied to the BrowseGallry Items property:-
SortByColumns(Filter('Promotions', StartsWith(PromoTitle, TxtSearch.Text) && StartDate>=DatePick.SelectedDate && PromoCategory=searchTerm), "PromoTitle", If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending))

The formula above works until I change the category to All.  I have tried feeding "" and " " into the searchTerm variable via UpdateContext, but neither work.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few alternatives you can use for this.

You can use another `StartsWith` condition, and set the search term to `""`. If the possible values of `PromoCategory` are `Male` and `Female`, then this should work (since everything "starts with" an empty string):

```
SortByColumns(
    Filter(
        'Promotions',
        StartsWith(PromoTitle, TxtSearch.Text) &&
            StartDate >= DatePick.SelectedDate &&
            StartsWith(PromoCategory, searchTerm)),
    "PromoTitle",
    If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending))
```

Another option is to use an `If` condition, so that if the search term is empty, then

```
SortByColumns(
    Filter(
        'Promotions',
        StartsWith(PromoTitle, TxtSearch.Text) &&
            StartDate >= DatePick.SelectedDate &&
            If(searchTerm = "", true, PromoCategory = searchTerm)),
    "PromoTitle",
    If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending))
```

Hope this helps!